# How to read large text file and save each word into mongodb using nodejs?

Tags: javascript

I have to a big text file which has a lot of comments in simple text form and what I need to do is read all the text from this file and separate every word individually and count their occurrence in the file. But due to file is very big and can not save all data in a variable. It just gives me the error.

`FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

CODE:

```
var userModel = require("./user");
var filename = "./test.txt";
const readStream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
readStream.on("data", function(chunk) {
    output += eol.auto(chunk.toString("utf8"));
});
readStream.on("end", function() {
    console.log("finished reading", output);
// mongo code goes here
});
```

Example :

File `test.txt` has text "My lovely Pat has one of the GREAT voices of her generation". So it should be like :

```
{
 "My" : 1,
 "lovely" : 1,
 "Pat" : 1,
 "has" : 1,
"one" : 1,
"of" : 2,
"the" : 1,
"GREAT" : 1,
"voices" : 1,
"her" : "1",
"generation" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't read all the file at once. Try to process the data as early as you can.

In your event handler :

```
readStream.on("data", function(chunk) {
```

Parse the data you can, and insert into mongodb right away.

If you can't make sense of the chunk, save it somewhere and try again with the next chunk.

Comment: You mean ```pause``` and ```resume``` the stream after few data read.

Comment: I don't. Just process it in your data handler instead of in your end handler.

Comment: I think the issue is that I can not save that much amount of data in a javascript variable and I can only save the data into the database when I get whole data because I need to do some calculation on it.